# looking for a postcode radius search for Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

looking for a postcode radius search for joomla.

enter postcode, select radius

displays all entrys from the database of postcodes that fall within that radius.

Cheers

Comment: So have you tried Google?

Comment: show here what you already did do solve your issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all Zipcodes within specified distance of a zipcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762248/find-all-zipcodes-within-specified-distance-of-a-zipcode)

Comment: i have already googled alot, mostly American, but im looking for something similar to this website (does anyone know the theme of the wordpress site?, i get localregister but cant find nothing): http://www.local-physio.co.uk/

Comment: @BrianHoover isn't that American? im looking for something similar to local-physio.co.uk

Comment: @Lodder do you know of any postcode radius searchs for joomla in the uk? searching on google bring back nothing relevant

Comment: Well, you start by using the postal code list at a site like: http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php which has the conversion from postal code to lat/long.  Then you use the same algorithm to figure out the +- range of lat/long and put that in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used SobiPro Radius search before and it worked well for what I needed.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/sobipro-extensions/19800

Good luck!

Comment: this looks near enough what I want, thanks - this is the most helpful answer I had.